# Jest not picking latest plugin from babel.config.js

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-jest, babel-plugin

I have my own babel plugin mentioned in `babel.config.js` and when I change the plugin, jest doesn't pick the updated plugin code and breaks tests. When I run
`npx jest --no-cache`, updated changes are picked up.

I do not want to run with `--no-cache` everytime I update the plugin.

I am curious to know how jest picks the latest babel plugins, when they are updated in npm artifactory?

I have mentioned my plugin in `babel.config.js` as:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];
  const plugins = [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    ["module:@babel-plugin-dynamic-import-override", {
      options: someOptions
    }]
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

Also, what changes do I make to my `jest.config.js` to make it pick the latest plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest caches the babel config for performance boost. This is same as providing `cacheDirectory: true` with `babel-loader` in webpack. `babel-loader` also has option to burst cache using `cacheIdentifier`, which jest doesn't has as of now and doesn't plan to add it in future too.

However, there is workaround by extending babel-jest.
Detailed discussion can be read here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8932